# How to make a zig-zag line in Sketch?

Tags: shapes, sketch-app

I was wondering how to make such lines in Sketch:

[image: various samples of zigzag lines]

[source](http://creativenerds.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/waveyandcurvyzigzagline.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an interesting solution [elsewhere on the internet](https://www.reddit.com/r/sketchapp/comments/39uzrk/how_do_you_make_zigzag_wavy_lines/): use the grid tool.

Draw the first 3 points using the `vector` tool (<kbd>V</kbd>) and then <kbd>Arrange</kbd> > <kbd>Make Grid...</kbd>.

There you define 1 row and how many repetitions you want as columns, with  Margin 0px. After that you better use <kbd>Layer</kbd> > <kbd>Path</kbd> > <kbd>Join</kbd> to make it a single object.

For the sinusoidal lines you just convert the points from `Straight` to `Mirrored` and delete the first and last point, as this will deform them. Play around with horizontal or vertical scale if you want to make the shapes tighter.